# Convert Firebase field array to list

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to convert a field which has an array in Firebase Cloud Firestore. The field is stored in a document and contains 10 values in the field.

I can get the data using the following code however I would like to know if its possible to convert this data into a List?

```
public void getAllowedPostcodes(){
    DocumentReference docRef = 
db.collection("AllowedPostcodes").document("tmGzpfFPFTwGw28uS8y1");

    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried the following however, it doesn't compile saying:

```
"Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)"
```

This is my code:

```
List<String> allowedData = new ArrayList<String>(task.getResult().getData());
```

The database structure is as follows:
[image]

Comment: try using `new ArrayList<String>((List)task.getResult().getData().values());`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RosárioPereiraFernandes. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It throws the following error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a forEach loop to iterate through each field, cast it to String and add it to the ArrayList:

```
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.getResult().getData());
                        for(Object item : task.getResult().getData().values())
                            allowedData.add(item.toString());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. That still gives me an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: I managed to get it to work using for(Object item : task.getResult().getData().values()) {
                            allowedData.add(item.toString());

Comment: Glad you did. I was gonna suggest that next :) .. I've updated my answer to match it